# Can't override mui checkbox or radio buttons

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

i have tried everything to override mui checkbox and radio from theme with no luck

```
components: {
...
MuiCheckbox: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          color: pallette.lightBlack,
        },
        colorSecondary: {
          '&$checked': {
            color: pallette.lightBlack,
          },
        },
      },
    },
    MuiRadio: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          color: pallette.lightBlack,
        },
        colorSecondary: {
          '&$checked': {
            color: pallette.lightBlack,
          },
        },
      },
    },
```

So far not able to make that work only from sx prop like this

```
<Radio
                  sx={{
                    '&, &.Mui-checked': {
                      color: pallette.lightBlack,
                    },
                  }}
                />
```

Answer (score 4):

I was dealing with this issue too using MUI v5.8
In order to override the styled for the radio both checked and unchecked, something like this worked for me.

```
MuiRadio: {
  styleOverrides: {
    root: {
      color: palette.secondary,
      "&.Mui-checked": {
        color: palette.secondary,
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The & allows you to select the Mui-checked class. This can be used in many places when overriding the styles. Check the assigned classes for the components your are looking to override.

Answer (score 1):

You might misspelled palette. Try changing pallette to palette.

Comment: its an object, is working like that

Comment: are you using Mui V5 or V4

Comment: im using mui5 all other overrides work properly